# Библиотека для верстки слайдера

Tags: слайдер

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какую лучше библиотеку использовать для такого слайдера?
Всегда использую slick, но не могу придумать, как при помощи неё сделать.
Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

embla.js, github.com/davidcetinkaya/embla-carousel, использую часто и очень нравится. Можно использовать в компонентах и просто при верстке.

Comment: Мне бы примерчик такого слайдера, как мне нужно, с такой библиотекой

Comment: http://sazanya-bukhta.ru/numbers/

Comment: http://sazanya-bukhta.ru/fotoalbom/ тут в отзывах добавил

Comment: Спасибо, но мне надо, как на скриншоте. Чтобы слайдеры как бы "складывались"